# flink cep sql Event Not triggering

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-cep

I use CEP Pattern in Flink SQL which is working as expected connecting to Kafka broker. But when i connecting to cluster based cloud kafka setup, the Flink CEP is not triggering. Here is my sql:

```
create table agent_action_detail 
(
    agent_id String, 
    room_id String, 
    create_time Bigint, 
    call_type String, 
    application_id String, 
    connect_time Bigint, 
    row_time TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3), WATERMARK for row_time as row_time  - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) 
with ('connector'='kafka', 'topic'='agent-action-detail', ...)
```

then I send messages in json format like

```
{"agent_id":"agent_221","room_id":"room1","create_time":1635206828877,"call_type":"inbound","application_id":"app1","connect_time":1635206501735,"row_time":"2021-10-25 16:07:09.019Z"}
```

in flink web ui, watermark works fine
[flink web ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEZLK.png)

I run my cep sql :

```
select * from agent_action_detail
 match_recognize(
    partition by agent_id 
    order by row_time 
    measures 
        last(BF.create_time) as create_time, 
        first(AF.connect_time) as connect_time 
    one row per match AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW 
    pattern (BF+ AF) define BF as BF.connect_time > 0 ,AF as AF.connect_time > 0
 )
```

every kafka message, connect_time is > 0, but flink not triggering.
Can somebody help to this issue, thanks in advance!

---

```
select * from agent_action_detail match_recognize( partition by agent_id order by row_time  measures AF.connect_time as connect_time one row per match pattern (BF AF) WITHIN INTERVAL '1' second define BF as (last(BF.connect_time, 1) < 1), AF as AF.connect_time >= 100)
```

Here is another cep sql still not working.
And the agent_action_detail table is insert by another flink sql as

```
insert into agent_action_detail select data.agent_id, data.room_id, data.create_time, data.call_type, data.application_id, data.connect_time, now() from source_table where type = 'xxx'
```

Comment: I have tried many other patterns should trigger, but none triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that can cause pattern matching to produce no results:

- the input doesn't actually contain the pattern
- watermarking is being done incorrectly
- the pattern is pathological in some way

This particular pattern loops with no exit condition. This sort of pattern doesn't allow the internal state of the pattern matching engine to ever be cleared, which will lead to problems.

If you were using Flink CEP directly, I would tell you to
try adding `until(condition)` or `within(time)` to constrain the number of possible matches.

With `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, see if you can add a distinct terminating element to the pattern.

---

Update: since you are still getting no results after modifying the pattern, you should determine if watermarking is the source of your problem. CEP relies on sorting the input stream by time, which depends on watermarking -- but only if you are using event time.

The easiest way to test this would be to switch to using processing time:

```sql
create table agent_action_detail 
(
    agent_id String, 
    ...
    row_time AS PROCTIME()
)
with (...)
```

If that works, then either the timestamps or watermarks are the problem. For example, if all of the events are late, you'll get no results. In your case, I'm wondering the row_time column has any data in it.

---

If that doesn't reveal the problem, please share a minimal reproducible example, including the data needed to observe the problem.

Comment: select * from ekyc_dashboard_agent_action_detail match_recognize( partition by agent_id order by row_time  measures AF.connect_time as connect_time one row per match pattern (BF AF) WITHIN INTERVAL '1' second define BF as (last(BF.connect_time, 1) < 1), AF as AF.connect_time >= 100)                                    
I  can help to see this sql ?

Comment: You want to end the pattern with something different from the looping part of your pattern. The problem here is that AF and BF are defined exactly the same.

Comment: I absolutely agree BF as BF.connect_time > 0 ,AF as AF.connect_time > 0 is the same. But when I update my BF AF to "BF as (last(BF.connect_time, 1) < 1), AF as AF.connect_time >= 100) "  It still not work.   I sat blocked and clueless for two solid days. > <...

Comment: David, I use proctime() and I works! Many thanks. Then I will keep trying use event time. now I am so happy~